# Material Textfield text is displayed backwards but CupertinoTextfield text is displayed correctly Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a textfield connected to its `TextEditingController()`. Inside the `onChanged:` callback I perform a text check to only allow for time input.
When running on iOS `CupertinoTextfield` is used and it behaves as expected, at every input cursor moves so next digit is at the right position, so inputting 1000 will result in 10:00.
When running on web or Android `Material Textfield` is used instead, the problem is that text is displayed backward as the cursor stays at first position so inputting 1000 will result in 00:01 ..
I tried enabling `autofocus: true` , but doesn't help. I tried with `textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,` but didn't fixit either. I also tried a solution from another post here grabbing the controller selection and reapplying it on the checked text but it didn't help either.
What am I missing to set for Material Textfield ?
As always thank you very much for your time and help.

This is the widget:

```
Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: kIsWeb
                            ? TextField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                autofocus: true,
                                controller: monMorOp,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  TextSelection previousSelection =
                                      monMorOp.selection;
                                  monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                                  monMorOp.selection = previousSelection;
                                },
                              )
                            : Platform.isIOS
                                ? CupertinoTextField(
                                    keyboardType:
                                        TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                    controller: monMorOp,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                                    },
                                  )
                                : TextField(
                                    keyboardType:
                                        TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                    controller: monMorOp,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                                    },
                                  ),
                      ),
```

an this is the text checking method :

```
String validateTimeFormat(String value) {
    print('call back method called');
//    String numb = event.text;
    print('input text is $value');
    String cleanNumb = value.replaceAll(RegExp(':'), '').substring(0);
    print('cleaned input text is $cleanNumb');
    RegExp isDigit = RegExp(r'^[\d]{1,4}$'); // is digit 1 to 4 characters
//    RegExp isDigit = RegExp(r'^[\d]$'); // is digit
    RegExp input;
    String text;
    int lenght;
    String replaced;

    if (isDigit.hasMatch(cleanNumb)) {
      print('text is 1-4 digits');
      text = cleanNumb;
      lenght = text.length;
//      print('lenght is $lenght');

      if (lenght == 1) {
        // first digit
        //allow 0-2
        input = RegExp(r'^[0-2]$');
        input.hasMatch(text[0])
            ? print('text is : $text')
            : print('text is: not valid');
        return input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1]) ? text : '';
      } else if (lenght == 2) {
        // second digit
        int first = int.parse(text[0]);
        print('firstDigit is $first');
        if (first == 008 || first == 1) {
          // allow 0-9
          input = RegExp(r'^[0-9]$');
          input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1])
              ? print('text is : $text')
              : print('text is : ${text.substring(0, lenght - 1)}');
          return input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1])
              ? text
              : text.substring(0, lenght - 1);
        } else {
          // allow 0-3
          input = RegExp(r'^[0-3]$');
          input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1])
              ? print('text is : $text')
              : print('text is : ${text.substring(0, lenght - 1)}');
          return input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1])
              ? text
              : text.substring(0, lenght - 1);
        }
      }
      if (lenght == 3) {
        //third digit
        // add : at lenght-1
        // allow 0-5
        input = RegExp(r'^[0-5]$');
        input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1])
            ? replaced = text.replaceRange(2, lenght, ':${text.substring(2)}')
            : replaced = text.substring(0, lenght - 1);
        print('text is : $replaced');
        return replaced;
      }
      if (lenght == 4) {
        // fourth digit
        // allow 0-9
        input = RegExp(r'^[0-9]$');
        input.hasMatch(text[lenght - 1])
            ? replaced = text.replaceRange(2, lenght, ':${text.substring(2)}')
            : replaced = text.substring(0, lenght - 1);
        print('text is : $replaced');
        return replaced;
      }
    } else {
      // discard extra digit
      print('more than 4 digits');
      lenght = cleanNumb.length;
      replaced =
          cleanNumb.replaceRange(2, lenght, ':${cleanNumb.substring(2, 4)}');
      print('text is : $replaced');
      return replaced;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After almost a month I found a solution to the problem thanks to jwehrle answer here [how to set cursor position at the end of the value in flutter in textfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851701/how-to-set-cursor-position-at-the-end-of-the-value-in-flutter-in-textfield/59525664?noredirect=1#comment111131305_59525664). I actually filed an issue to the Flutter team as `Material Textfield` behaves different from `CupertinoTextfield` when assigning a manipulated text to its `TextEditingController` and it seems to be platform related, I only tested it on web and iPad.
I think of this solution more of a workaround as this shouldn't be necessary as it isn't needed in `CupertinoTextfield` on iOS.

In `onChanged:` callback add this after assigning the manipulated input text to the controller:

`textfieldController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: textfieldController.text.length));`

## In use:

```
Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: UniversalPlatform.isWeb
                            ? TextField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                autofocus: true,
                                controller: monMorOp,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                                  monMorOp.selection =
                                      TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
                                          offset: monMorOp.text.length));
                                },
                              )
                            : UniversalPlatform.isIOS
                                ? CupertinoTextField(
                                    keyboardType:
                                        TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                    controller: monMorOp,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                                    },
                                  )
                                : TextField(
                                    keyboardType:
                                        TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                                    controller: monMorOp,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                                      monMorOp.selection =
                                          TextSelection.fromPosition(
                                              TextPosition(
                                                  offset:
                                                      monMorOp.text.length));
                                    },
                                  ),
                      ),
```

## update 8 aug 2020:

As I upgraded to Catalina, Android Studio 4.0 the workaround is now needed also for iOS. Not sure if it's due to a change in iOS 13.5 or Flutter.. but on web it now scrambles digits in pair..
Looks like the fixed something and broken something else..

## flutter doctor on Catalina:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-8.0.pre.98, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 1.21.0-8.0.pre.98 at /Users/vinnytwice/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 77b4505c80 (31 hours ago), 2020-08-06 18:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision cd3ea1e839
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-3.0.dev fcafd43f2c)

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/vinnytwice/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (mobile) • 08E2351F-A170-4C2E-A8DE-8FED3B5E3124 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5 (simulator)
    • Web Server (web)                               • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter
      Tools
    • Chrome (web)                                   • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google
      Chrome 84.0.4147.105

• No issues found!
```

## Update 4 Feb 2021

Instead of assigning the new Textfield's value from the `onChanged` callback to it's controller's `.text` parameter after the text formatting it as

```
monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
```

and then displacing the controller selection by offsetting it of the controller's `.text.length` amount as

```
monMorOp.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: monMorOp.text.length));
```

I now assign the new and formatted Textfield text to the controller's `.value` and offset its selection position by the Textfield's formatted value as

```
 onChanged: (value) {
     value = validateTimeFormat(value);
     monMorCl.value = TextEditingValue(
           text: value,
           selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: value.length));
 },
```

Hope it helps others as I see this is quite changing lately with any Flutter/Dart update.
Cheers

Comment: @gogobebe2 indeed it doesn't work anymore.. i can't test on iPad but running the app an android presents the same issue that on web..

Comment: @gogobebe2 didi you solve it? Please check the February update in my answer to see if works fo you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a similar thing, I'm fairly sure its not directly the Material TextField's fault though, as its fine if I compile + run it on an Android emulator. It is however wrong when compiling the same code for desktop.

Did you report a bug?

Still broken for me @

```
Flutter 2.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision adc687823a (2 weeks ago) • 2021-04-16 09:40:20 -0700
Engine • revision b09f014e96
Tools • Dart 2.12.3
```

Aha: Its a gtk+ version issue, see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47745 - you need at least 3.24.27 (I have 3.24.26 ... typical)

Comment: didi you see the `Update 4 Feb 2021` in my answer? It works if assigning the `value` from the textfield's `onChanged` callback to the textfield's controller `.value` property ( instead that to its `.text` parameter, which is used just to assign an initial value when page inits for instance) and offset the cursor by the `value.length` amount..

Comment: I did, but I fixed mine by upgrading gtk+ rather than working around it

Answer (score 0):

```
class FixedOffsetTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  set text(String newText) {
    value = value.copyWith(
      text: newText,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length),
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );
  }
}
```

This worked for me as of 04/02/2021 :)

Comment: Very nice, then from the textfield's  `onChanged: (value) { }` callback you just set `controller.text = value` ? Within a setState(){} or not ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: No luck here, whenever I assign to the `TextEditingController.text` the `onChanged` value it shows it backward as the cursor stays at the beginning of the textfield. So if on top I use my validator (which works as intended and is not the problem here) before assigning the `TextEditingController.text` the `onChanged` value it gets scrambled ..
What Flutter channel and Dart version are you using ? I'm on Channel stable, 1.22.6  / Dart version 2.10.5

Comment: I updated my answer as I found a working solution if you want to check if it fixes your problem too. There is no need to extend the TextEditing controller. It does work properly using the `.value` instead of `.text` parameter. Cheers