# How to fix the cursor movement with onChange event of flutter?

Tags: flutter, onchange

The cursor is continuously moving to front while typing data in text field.
Before it is not there but once I wired onChange event, it is happening.

My issue:

[image: Issue with TextField]

My code:

```
 Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: descriptionController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Any Details',
            hintText: "e.g. Whatever details you want to save",
            labelStyle: textStyle,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
            ),
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          onChanged: (String string){
            setState(() {
              if (string != null){
                coinOrder.description = string;
              }


            });
          },
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Can this post help ? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851701/how-to-set-cursor-position-at-the-end-of-the-value-in-flutter-in-textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851701/how-to-set-cursor-position-at-the-end-of-the-value-in-flutter-in-textfield)

Comment: It seems this issue is fixed partially, now after setting the project level sdk, this error is not coming. But, android debug bridge is not working. Can you see this once https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyDkHQeQVyA

Comment: See this post maybe, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio)

Comment: My TextField issue not fixed yet, sorry for the wrong information as comment earlier, as I typed here by mistake instead of other post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onFieldSubmitted
that will work too
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dve0N.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remove the controller

Comment: It was the reason why you are having that issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use one string variable to store value so this issue will not accrue.
see the below code.

```
String? details;
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: descriptionController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Any Details',
            hintText: "e.g. Whatever details you want to save",
            labelStyle: textStyle,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
            ),
          ),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          onChanged: (String string){
            setState(() {
              if (string != null){
                //coinOrder.description = string;
                details=string;
              }


            });
          },
        ),
      )
```